# On differentiability and Fourier coefficients; Vretblad

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

### Background

I'm reading Vretblad's Fourier Analysis and its Applications. In the chapter on Fourier series, there is a section on differentiable functions.

Let $\mathbb T$ be the unit circle and denote the complex Fourier coefficient of $f$ by $c_n$. Then there is the following theorem;

> Theorem 4.4 If $f\in C^k(\mathbb T)$, then $|c_n|\leq M/|n|^k$ for some constant $M$.

This theorem is not really proved in the book, but if $f$ is (Riemann) integrable over $\mathbb T$, then the Fourier coefficients are bounded. This follows from the definition of $c_n$, namely $$|c_n|=\left|\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t)e^{-int}dt\right|\leq \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left|f(t)\right|\left|e^{-int}\right|dt=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |f(t)|dt=M,$$ since $f$ is integrable over $\mathbb T$. To "prove" the theorem, if $b_n$ denotes the Fourier coefficient of $f^{(k)}$, then by recursively applying partial integration, and noting that if $g$ is continuous on $\mathbb T$, then $g(\pi)=g(-\pi)$, so
\begin{align} b_n &= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\mathbb T}f^{(k)}(t)e^{-int}dt  \\ &= \frac{1}{2\pi}[f^{(k-1)}(t)e^{-int}]^{\pi}_{-\pi}+\frac{1}{2\pi}in\int_{\mathbb T}f^{(k-1)}(t)e^{-int} dt  \\ &= \ldots \\ &=(in)^k \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\mathbb T}f(t)e^{-int}dt \\ &= (in)^kc_n.\end{align}
Since $f^{(k)}$ is continuous (and thus integrable), we have $|b_n|\leq M$ for some $M$, i.e. $|n^k c_n|\leq M$, and the claim of the theorem follows.

### Questions

There is the following exercise in the book;

> Try to prove the following partial improvements of Theorem 4.4:
>
> (a) If $f'$ is continuous and differentiable on $\mathbb T$ except possibly for a finite number of jump discontinuities, then $|c_n|\leq M/|n|$ for some constant $M$.
>
> (b) If $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb T$ and has a second derivative everywhere except possibly for a finite number of points, where there are "corners" (i.e., the left-hand and right-hand first derivative exist but are different from each other), then $|c_n|\leq M/n^2$ for some constant $M$.

1. I struggle with seeing the difference in the assumptions of these two statements. Is (a) not assuming the same as (b)?
2. Consider statement (a) and the assumptions on $f'$. What does this tell us about $f$? I've been trying to compute the Fourier coefficients of $f'$ as above for the "proof" of theorem 4.4, i.e. via partial integration, but I'm not sure what properties $f$ has.
3. Any hints for (b)?

Grateful for any help.

Comment: this is a bit weird as $(a)$ to me sounds like a typo and it should read something like $f$ continuous and differentiable with derivative continuous except at a few jump points (where the derivative is one-sided continuous also, but the discontinuities of $f$ are finitely many jumps only - the function $x$ on $(-\pi, \pi]$ extended by periodicity is such an example) and the proof follows by integration by parts again because the conditions above mean $f$ has bounded variation); for $(b)$ you need a condition on the second derivative too like integrability because otherwise result not true

Comment: @Conrad I agree (a) seems like a typo. Maybe the author meant $f$ instead of $f'$. Denote the coefficient of $f'$ by $b_n$, and assume it has a single jump discontinuity at $t=-\pi$, then when I proceed with partial integration, I get \begin{align} b_n &= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\mathbb T}f'(t)e^{-int}dt  \\ &= \frac{1}{2\pi}[f(t)e^{-int}]^{\pi}_{-\pi}+\frac{1}{2\pi}in\int_{\mathbb T}f(t)e^{-int} dt  .\end{align} Does $[f(t)e^{-int}]^{\pi}_{-\pi}$ evaluate to zero despite $f(\pi)\neq f(-\pi)$?

Comment: why does that matter? you still get $\frac{1}{2\pi}in\int_{\mathbb T}f(t)e^{-int} dt$ is a uniformly bounded number (by $|b_n|$ and $|f(t)e^{-int}]^{\pi}_{-\pi}|$ the latter being bounded by the variation of $f$)

Comment: @Conrad I don't understand what you mean by $|f(t)e^{-int}]^{\pi}_{-\pi}|$ is bounded by the variation of $f$. Could you elaborate?

Comment: $|f(t)e^{-int}]^{\pi}_{-\pi}|=|f(\pi)-f(-\pi)| \le 2||f||$ for example (or more generally bounded by the variation of $f$) - note though that you have to be careful with $b_n$ and show that they are uniformly bounded too as $f'$ is also only piecewise (defined and) continuous; the simpler proof is to note that if $f$ is bounded variation (not necessarily continuous but periodic), then $df$ is a finite measure so you can integrate by parts directly and get exactly as above $|\frac{1}{2\pi}in\int_{\mathbb T}f(t)e^{-int} dt| =|\int_{\mathbb T}e^{int}df| \le 2\pi \int_{\mathbb T}|df|$

Comment: meant $|in\int_{\mathbb T}f(t)e^{-int} dt| =|\int_{\mathbb T}e^{-int}df| \le \int_{\mathbb T}|df|$

Comment: @Conrad ok, from my comment above then, we obtain \begin{align} |b_n| &= \left|\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\mathbb T}f'(t)e^{-int}dt \right| \\ &\leq\frac{\lVert f\rVert}{\pi} +|nc_n|  .\end{align} The desired inequality in (a) is $|c_n|\leq M/|n|$. How can I get that from the computation above?

Comment: That is not quite right - you pass the $f$ term to the left and get $nc_n=b_n+f_n$ so $|nc_n| \le |b_n|+||f||/\pi$ and then you show as usual that $|b_n|\le M$ so done

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150823/discussion-between-psie-and-conrad).